# How to unslick without deleting the HTML?

Tags: slick.js

Is there a way with slick to use responsive settings to unslick and reslick the slider below and above certain resolutions automatically?

I tried to use the simple method

```
var rooms = jQuery('.room-slides').slick({
    dots: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    draggable: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    adaptiveHeight: false,
    variableWidth: true,
    responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 960,
      settings: "unslick"
    }
    ]
});
```

However below 960px the entire HMTL is deleted from the DOM, I thought the "destroy" method was only for de-attach all CSS/JS associated not the entire slider.